# How to set data that is parsed from the inner array of the json

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

I have a nested array json where I have to parse. Below is the json

```
{
    "result": {

        "course": [{
                    "course_id": "3",
                    "parent_course_id": "0",
                    "course_name": "Management of Portfolio (MoP)",
                    "course_price": "51000",
                    "course_price_doller": "510",
                    "course_price_discunt": "40000",
                    "course_price_discunt_doller": "400",
                    "course_discunt_date": "2016-08-09",
                    "course_description": "We are an expert training organization with our faculty having vast experience in consulting and training accredited by Peoplecert on behalf of Axelos.\r\nThis program is for 3 full days.\r\n\r\nXellentro has one of the best Project Portfolio Management Professionals with large experience of project management and consulting in the area across the globe for large organizations and governments.",
                    "course_image": "http:\/\/arrisofttech.com\/2016\/xellentroapp\/assets\/uploads\/course\/SL5715320A694D7_COURSE_128x64.jpg",
                    "total_module": 3,
                    "module": [{
                        "module_id": "14",
                        "video_price": "12",
                        "video_price_doller": "11",
                        "video_price_discunt": "123",
                        "video_price_discunt_doller": "12",
                        "video_discunt_date": "2016-02-03",
                        "video_type": "1",
                        "video_link": "arrisofttech.com\/2016\/xellentroapp\/video\/sample_2.mp4",
                        "video_image": "http:\/\/arrisofttech.com\/2016\/xellentroapp\/assets\/uploads\/course\/SL571531558C660_COURSE_228x80.png",
                        "video_description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                    }, {
                        "module_id": "12",
                        "video_price": "12",
                        "video_price_doller": "11",
                        "video_price_discunt": "123",
                        "video_price_discunt_doller": "12",
                        "video_discunt_date": "2016-02-03",
                        "video_type": "0",
                        "video_link": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=QSaWoca3SjY&list=RDQSaWoca3SjY",
                        "video_image": "http:\/\/arrisofttech.com\/2016\/xellentroapp\/assets\/uploads\/course\/SL571531558C660_COURSE_228x80.png",
                        "video_description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                    }, {
                        "module_id": "13",
                        "video_price": "12",
                        "video_price_doller": "11",
                        "video_price_discunt": "123",
                        "video_price_discunt_doller": "12",
                        "video_discunt_date": "2016-02-03",
                        "video_type": "0",
                        "video_link": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=QSaWoca3SjY&list=RDQSaWoca3SjY",
                        "video_image": "http:\/\/arrisofttech.com\/2016\/xellentroapp\/assets\/uploads\/course\/SL571531558C660_COURSE_228x80.png",
                        "video_description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                    }]
}]
            }
}
```

There are two JsonArray:- more specifically Array within an Array namely **COURSE** and **MODULE** I have already parsed the json but the point is there will be a listview where the courses will be shown. on the click of the item it will open an activity which will shpw the total modules in the listview. I have already listed the course but on the item or the button click I can't show the modules in the listview. Below I am attaching the code for the same.

**TrainningFragment.java**

```
    public class TrainingFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ImageView tag;
    private static final String url = "http://arrisofttech.com/2016/xellentroapp/webservices/tranning/";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> trainingList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    public static final String KEY_URL = "video_url";
    public TrainingFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), trainingList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please Wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                hidePDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject result = response.getJSONObject("result");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("course");
                    System.out.println("Course: == >" + result.getJSONArray("course"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject trainingObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setCourse_id(trainingObj.getString("course_id"));
                        movie.setParent_course_id(trainingObj.getString("parent_course_id"));
                        movie.setCourse_name(trainingObj.getString("course_name"));
                        movie.setCourse_price(trainingObj.getString("course_price"));
                        movie.setCourse_price_dollar(trainingObj.getString("course_price_doller"));
                        movie.setCourse_price_discount_dollar(trainingObj.getString("course_price_discunt_doller"));
                        movie.setCourse_discount_date(trainingObj.getString("course_discunt_date"));
                        movie.setCourse_description(trainingObj.getString("course_description"));
                        movie.setCourse_image(trainingObj.getString("course_image"));
                        JSONArray module = trainingObj.getJSONArray("module");
                        for (int j = 0; j < module.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject moduleObj = module.getJSONObject(j);
                            movie.setModule_id(moduleObj.getString("module_id"));
                            movie.setVideo_price(moduleObj.getString("video_price"));
                            movie.setVideo_price_doller(moduleObj.getString("video_price_doller"));
                            movie.setVideo_price_discunt(moduleObj.getString("video_price_discunt"));
                            movie.setVideo_price_discunt_doller(moduleObj.getString("video_price_discunt_doller"));
                            movie.setVideo_discunt_date(moduleObj.getString("video_discunt_date"));
                            movie.setVideo_type(moduleObj.getString("video_type"));
                            movie.setVideo_link(moduleObj.getString("video_link"));
                            movie.setVideo_image(moduleObj.getString("video_image"));
                            movie.setVideo_description(moduleObj.getString("video_description"));
                        }
                        trainingList.add(movie);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("No Connectivity ").setMessage("Please check your internet connectivity!").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();
                hidePDialog();
            }
        }));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCustomListAdapter**

```
 add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                add_to_cart_list.add(m.getCourse_id().toString());
                add_to_cart_list.size();
                pDialog.setMessage("Added to the cart ...");
                showDialog();
                StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        URL_ADD_TO_CART, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Added to Cart", "Adding to the cart: " + response.toString());
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Adding to the cart: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(activity,
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("app_id", "12365478965874");
                        params.put("product_type", "1");
                        params.put("parent_course_id", m.getParent_course_id());
                        params.put("course_id", m.getCourse_id());
                        params.put("vaideo_id", "0");
                        params.put("product_image", m.getCourse_image());
                        params.put("product_name", m.getCourse_name());
                        params.put("product_price", m.getCourse_price_dollar());
                        params.put("product_discunt_price", m.getCourse_price_discount_dollar());
                        params.put("product_quantity", "1");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, "ADD TO CART");
            }
            private void showDialog() {
                if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.show();
            }

            private void hideDialog() {
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        view_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(activity, "This functionality is under Development Phase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//               activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, ViewDetails.class));


                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ViewDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("course_image", m.getCourse_image());
                intent.putExtra("course_name", m.getCourse_name());
                intent.putExtra("course_price", m.getCourse_price_discount_dollar());
                intent.putExtra("course_price_discount", m.getCourse_price_dollar());
                intent.putExtra("course_description", m.getCourse_description());
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn_view_module.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent view_module = new Intent(activity, ViewModule.class);

                Toast.makeText(activity, m.getCourse_id() + " " + m.getModule_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                activity.startActivity(view_module);
            }
        });
```

Here there are 3 buttons:-

addtocart, viewmodule and view course. by clicking on the viewmodule button, an activity will open with a custom list specifying the modules of the course. In the above json the total number of array elements are 3 so 3 listview items will be shown with the above specified components

**ViewDetails.java**

```
public class ViewDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean enableBackNavigation;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView tv_course_name, tv_course_actual_price, tv_course_discounted_price, tv_course_description;
    private String course_image = "", course_name = "", course_actual_price = "", course_discounted_price = "", course_description = "";
    private  NetworkImageView thumbNail;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_details);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            course_image = intent.getStringExtra("course_image");
            course_name = intent.getStringExtra("course_name");
            course_actual_price = intent.getStringExtra("course_price");
            course_discounted_price = intent.getStringExtra("course_price_discount");
            course_description = intent.getStringExtra("course_description");
        }
        init();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        if (enableBackNavigation) {
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }
        if (imageLoader == null)imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(course_image, imageLoader);
        tv_course_name.setText(course_name);
        tv_course_actual_price.setText(course_actual_price);
        tv_course_actual_price.setPaintFlags(tv_course_actual_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        tv_course_discounted_price.setText(course_discounted_price);
        tv_course_description.setText(course_description);

    }

    private void init() {
        tv_course_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.course_name);
        tv_course_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.course_description);
        tv_course_actual_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actual_cost);
        tv_course_discounted_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.discounted_cost);
        thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Movie.class**

```
public class Movie {
    private String course_id;
    private String parent_course_id;
    private String course_name;
    private String course_price;
    private String course_price_dollar;
    private String course_price_discount_dollar;
    private String course_discount_date;
    private String course_description;
    private String course_image;
    private String total_module;
    // Module
    private String module_id;
    private String video_price;
    private String video_price_doller;
    private String video_price_discunt;
    private String video_price_discunt_doller;
    private String video_discunt_date;
    private String video_type;
    private String video_link;
    private String video_image;
    private String video_description;


    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String course_id, String parent_course_id, String course_name, String course_price,
                 String course_price_dollar, String course_price_discount_dollar, String course_discount_date,
                 String course_description, String course_image, String total_module, String module_id,
                 String video_price, String video_price_doller, String video_price_discunt,
                 String video_price_discunt_doller, String video_discunt_date, String video_type,
                 String video_link, String video_image, String video_description) {
        this.course_id = course_id;
        this.parent_course_id = parent_course_id;
        this.course_name = course_name;
        this.course_price = course_price;
        this.course_price_dollar = course_price_dollar;
        this.course_price_discount_dollar = course_price_discount_dollar;
        this.course_discount_date = course_discount_date;
        this.course_description = course_description;
        this.course_image = course_image;
        this.total_module = total_module;
        this.module_id = module_id;
        this.video_price = video_price;
        this.video_price_doller = video_price_doller;
        this.video_price_discunt = video_price_discunt;
        this.video_price_discunt_doller = video_price_discunt_doller;
        this.video_discunt_date = video_discunt_date;
        this.video_type = video_type;
        this.video_link = video_link;
        this.video_image = video_image;
        this.video_description = video_description;
    }

    public String getCourse_id() {
        return course_id;
    }

    public void setCourse_id(String course_id) {
        this.course_id = course_id;
    }

    public String getParent_course_id() {
        return parent_course_id;
    }

    public void setParent_course_id(String parent_course_id) {
        this.parent_course_id = parent_course_id;
    }

    public String getCourse_name() {
        return course_name;
    }

    public void setCourse_name(String course_name) {
        this.course_name = course_name;
    }

    public String getCourse_price() {
        return course_price;
    }

    public void setCourse_price(String course_price) {
        this.course_price = course_price;
    }

    public String getCourse_price_dollar() {
        return course_price_dollar;
    }

    public void setCourse_price_dollar(String course_price_dollar) {
        this.course_price_dollar = course_price_dollar;
    }

    public String getCourse_price_discount_dollar() {
        return course_price_discount_dollar;
    }

    public void setCourse_price_discount_dollar(String course_price_discount_dollar) {
        this.course_price_discount_dollar = course_price_discount_dollar;
    }

    public String getCourse_discount_date() {
        return course_discount_date;
    }

    public void setCourse_discount_date(String course_discount_date) {
        this.course_discount_date = course_discount_date;
    }

    public String getCourse_description() {
        return course_description;
    }

    public void setCourse_description(String course_description) {
        this.course_description = course_description;
    }

    public String getCourse_image() {
        return course_image;
    }

    public void setCourse_image(String course_image) {
        this.course_image = course_image;
    }

    public String getTotal_module() {
        return total_module;
    }

    public void setTotal_module(String total_module) {
        this.total_module = total_module;
    }

    public String getModule_id() {
        return module_id;
    }

    public void setModule_id(String module_id) {
        this.module_id = module_id;
    }

    public String getVideo_price() {
        return video_price;
    }

    public void setVideo_price(String video_price) {
        this.video_price = video_price;
    }

    public String getVideo_price_doller() {
        return video_price_doller;
    }

    public void setVideo_price_doller(String video_price_doller) {
        this.video_price_doller = video_price_doller;
    }

    public String getVideo_price_discunt() {
        return video_price_discunt;
    }

    public void setVideo_price_discunt(String video_price_discunt) {
        this.video_price_discunt = video_price_discunt;
    }

    public String getVideo_price_discunt_doller() {
        return video_price_discunt_doller;
    }

    public void setVideo_price_discunt_doller(String video_price_discunt_doller) {
        this.video_price_discunt_doller = video_price_discunt_doller;
    }

    public String getVideo_discunt_date() {
        return video_discunt_date;
    }

    public void setVideo_discunt_date(String video_discunt_date) {
        this.video_discunt_date = video_discunt_date;
    }

    public String getVideo_type() {
        return video_type;
    }

    public void setVideo_type(String video_type) {
        this.video_type = video_type;
    }

    public String getVideo_link() {
        return video_link;
    }

    public void setVideo_link(String video_link) {
        this.video_link = video_link;
    }

    public String getVideo_image() {
        return video_image;
    }

    public void setVideo_image(String video_image) {
        this.video_image = video_image;
    }

    public String getVideo_description() {
        return video_description;
    }

    public void setVideo_description(String video_description) {
        this.video_description = video_description;
    }
}
```

Please help. I got stuck here and I can't understand what to do.

Comment: Please post the code related to **I have already listed the course but on the item or the button click I can't show the modules in the listview.**

Comment: I have posted the code for the Trainning Fragment and also the code for the click event on the adapter

Comment: How do you show the details in `ViewDetails` activity? Post that code too.

Comment: your Json is wrong please correct it.. check here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @Prerak Sola: I have already given the code of ViewDetails

Comment: @Amol: I have editted the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In movie class add one Arraylist**

```
private String course_id;
    private String parent_course_id;
    private String course_name;
    private String course_price;
    private String course_price_dollar;
    private String course_price_discount_dollar;
    private String course_discount_date;
    private String course_description;
    private String course_image;
    private String total_module;
    // Module
    private String module_id;
    private String video_price;
    private String video_price_doller;
    private String video_price_discunt;
    private String video_price_discunt_doller;
    private String video_discunt_date;
    private String video_type;
    private String video_link;
    private String video_image;
    private String video_description;
    private List<Module> modulelist;
```

**Create one module class with the fields**

```
private String module_id;
    private String video_price;
    private String video_price_doller;
    private String video_price_discunt;
    private String video_price_discunt_doller;
    private String video_discunt_date;
    private String video_type;
    private String video_link;
    private String video_image;
    private String video_description;
```

**Then in trainig fetching the value**

```
JSONArray module = trainingObj.getJSONArray("module");
                        for (int j = 0; j < module.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject moduleObj = module.getJSONObject(j);
                            movie.setModule_id(moduleObj.getString("module_id"));
                            movie.setVideo_price(moduleObj.getString("video_price"));
                            movie.setVideo_price_doller(moduleObj.getString("video_price_doller"));
                            movie.setVideo_price_discunt(moduleObj.getString("video_price_discunt"));
                            movie.setVideo_price_discunt_doller(moduleObj.getString("video_price_discunt_doller"));
                            movie.setVideo_discunt_date(moduleObj.getString("video_discunt_date"));
                            movie.setVideo_type(moduleObj.getString("video_type"));
                            movie.setVideo_link(moduleObj.getString("video_link"));
                            movie.setVideo_image(moduleObj.getString("video_image"));
                            movie.setVideo_description(moduleObj.getString("video_description"));
                        }
```

**Now change this**

```
List<Module> mod1=new ArrayList<Module>();

    JSONArray module = trainingObj.getJSONArray("module");
    for (int j = 0; j < module.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject moduleObj = module.getJSONObject(j);
        Module modl=new Module();
        modl.setModule_id(moduleObj.getString("module_id"));
        modl.setVideo_price(moduleObj.getString("video_price"));
        modl.setVideo_price_doller(moduleObj.getString("video_price_doller"));
        modl.setVideo_price_discunt(moduleObj.getString("video_price_discunt"));
        modl.setVideo_price_discunt_doller(moduleObj.getString("video_price_discunt_doller"));
        modl.setVideo_discunt_date(moduleObj.getString("video_discunt_date"));
        modl.setVideo_type(moduleObj.getString("video_type"));
        modl.setVideo_link(moduleObj.getString("video_link"));
        modl.setVideo_image(moduleObj.getString("video_image"));
        modl.setVideo_description(moduleObj.getString("video_description"));
        mod1.add(j,modl);

    }
    movie.setModulelist(mod1);
```

**In movie.setModulelist you will get your list**